# Git: Why does rebase result in conflicts while merge does not?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm probably not getting something right, but could anyone explain to me why `git rebase` results in conflicts, while `git merge` (same branch) does not?

For as far as I know `git rebase` puts the commits from the other branch before the commits I made on my current branch, while `git merge` takes those same commits and applies them to my branch as patch, right? Is the `diff` then not the same, although maybe reversed? Not sure why patching my branch with the other commits is not a problem, while patching the other branch with my commits is.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I see that sometimes my question is still getting an upvote. Let me explain for those that do not understand the currently chosen answer, because I sure didn't when I read it for the first time.

Let's say you have branch `master` with commits `A`, `B` and `C`.

Then from commit `C` you create a new branch `mybranch`. You commit, and you get commits `D` and `E`.

In the meantime someone else commits `F` and `G` on master.

`master` then looks like this: `A B C F G`, while `mybranch` looks like this: `A B C D E`.

Now you have two merge strategies:

### Merge

While on `mybranch`, you type `git merge master`. It takes all the commits from `master` that you do not have on `mybranch` - `F` and `G`. It first merges `F` on top of your `E` (last commit of `mybranch`), and then merges `G` on top of `F`.

End result: `A B C D E F G`. Despite these letters being in the same order, the commits were not done (or may not have been done) in chronological order, because actually `F` and `G` were (or could have been) done before `D` and `E`. You will see a merge commit in this case as well.

### Rebase

While on `mybranch`, you type `git rebase master`. It takes all the commits from `master` that you do not have on `mybranch` - `F` and `G` and places those on top of your current branch, brining it in the state that `master` is currently in (because you branched from `master` and now get all commits that were done on `master` since you branched off). It then takes your first commit - `D` - and merges it on top of `G` (last commit that was done on `master`). Then it takes `E` and puts it on top of `D`.

End result: `A B C F G D E`. It looks as if no branch was ever split off `master`, and if master is one continuous work, because you kind of said "I want my branch to look as if it was just split off master and then my work was put on top of it". It is the equivalent of checking out `master` (now `A B C F G`), creating a new branch `mybranch` and then adding your commits (`A B C F G D E`).

### Why rebase might result in a conflict while merge does not.

Without going into details, let's just say that it could be that merging `master`'s `F` on top of `mybranch`'s `E` might not result in a conflict, but merging `mybranch`'s `D` on top of `master`'s `F` might. It just really depends on which code was changed an if it was a change that is compatible with the previous commit. Merge conflicts may arise in both cases.

Comment: Technically, in case of `rebase`, it will NOT put the exact commit hash `D` and `E` but rather create a new commit hashes `D'` and `E'`. So end result would be `A B C F G D' E'`.

Answer (score 17):

During a rebase, you apply all commits of some branch on top of another one. It is possible that one of those commits has a conflict that you  solved in a subsequent commit. Hence, the merge operation has no conflict whereas the rebase lead to intermediate conflicts.

See also [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) which allows you to automatically solve conflicts that you already solved.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm still not getting it wholly. Say my branch A has commits a, b and c. Then I create branch B with commits d and e. Commit f is made on branch A. **Rebase** (while on branch B) would result in: a, b, c, f, d, e; **merge** would result in: a, b, c, d, e, f. Now how on earth could commit f create a merge conflict with commit c if it was created on top of commit c on branch A in the first place?

Comment: @minitauros (1) A merge would result in two branches being joined: one with a,b,c,f and one with a,b,c,d,e, not a linear history. (2) If commit F, made on branch A, introduce no conflict, then I can't see how it could introduce a conflict when rebasing (if you have a more detailed example, that would be great). (3) But if D conflicts with F and E fixes that conflict, then a rebase would replay the conflict whereas a merge wouldn't.

Comment: Ok then, thanks for the explanation there! Does clear it up a bit. Unfortunately I do not have the example present any more (as I've fixed it), but if I run into it again and if the same question arises, I will update this post with more info :). For now I think this answer is good enough, thanks!