# Why this merge works fine (add a new file) while rebase resulted in conflict?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

[image: merge vs rebase]

commit **b2e01e2** added a new file, when merge it into the main branch at 4dee649, it works just fine, the new file was added.

While rebase **b2e01e2** onto the main branch will result in a conflict at another file.

The previous merge of the commit **84b064f** into the main branch at commit **7f5db59** was indeed caused a conflict at that file and it was resolved at **7f5db59**.

I checked the discussion at [Is merge without conflicts equivalent to rebase without conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530822/is-merge-without-conflicts-equivalent-to-rebase-without-conflicts). But the problem there was the rebased branch has a file conflicted with another file at the main branch, which is not my case.

This discussion [Git: Why does rebase result in conflicts while merge does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391714/git-why-does-rebase-result-in-conflicts-while-merge-does-not) said "It is possible that one of those commits has a conflict that you solved in a subsequent commit." seems to be my case. But I still don't have a clear idea why rebase the newly added file will resulted a conflict at another file.

My second question is when I better use merge instead of rebase ? In my case it seems that if there is ever a conflict in the branch since the common base(commit aee4164 in my case) I better use merge instead of rebase. But is this the case ?

Comment: Rebasing and merging between the same branches are potentially very different operations, although logically you might end up with the same result.  In a rebase, you rewind the target branch, and then eventually replay all your commits on top of a new base.  So, the conflicts you saw during the merge may not happen in the rebase, and vice-versa.

Comment: I know the basic idea of merge vs rebase. In my case I actually prefer rebase b/c I just want to add the new file into the main branch and I thought it should not have conflict. Hence the question.

Comment: And my comment explains why you are seeing this behavior.  While merging and rebasing logically introduce the exact same changes, they do so in potentially very different ways.  In general, you can't expect to get the same number/type of conflicts between merging and rebasing.

Comment: I knew what you said but your comments did not really answer  my questions.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you are merging you do *not* consider the change sets in the middle of the branches since they diverged. Git basically considers the differences between the tips of the two branches you are merging and the point where they diverged. If you have a revision on the other branch that might introduce a conflict but then there's a later revision that takes care of the conflict-originating section of code in a way that the conflict won't happen anymore (for example, reverting the revision that would have created a conflict.... not the only way but one that will certainly take care of the conclict), merge won't see the conflict pop up whereas when rebasing it will happen.

Comment: That is very much a question of taste. Is it a feature branch? If that's the case, would you mind squashing/rebasing it instead of rebasing all the revisions? I have even a post out there with a recipe for squashing/rebasing based on merge/reset. This is very much opinion-based, also a lot of previous experience... and how many tricks you have under your sleeve.